# Mysql Server Gone away on Hostgator server with magento

Tags: magento-1.9, database, shipping

I am having issue with a Magento website with 1.9.x version.
A strange issue started appearing.

I attached logs of Magento

[image]

Comment: Hard to know without more information.

Answer (score -1):

shared log is not enough to point out the exact error. It is not clear that if it is using any subquery in where clause.

I recommend check with the admin of site as if your server getting overloaded and mysql throwing the gone away due to reboot of mysql? Do you get server reports such as CPU usage by mysql, apache usage(plesk health monitor does that) . This will not be tracked in the log you have shared. Your admin need to consider all the facts as only the log shared might not be that helpful to identify issue.
Check if that table too big that query not coming out? Misconfiguration of various mysql db parameters which does memory allocation for the instance can also be a factor. DB table indexes might also be in incorrect state and may require analyze and optimiztion. Does this issue appear intermittently now or always it appear on the screen now?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimization.html

Sorry for a generic response but the inputs shared are not complete from your end so I tried to add more and see if that helps your admin to find the issue cause and then solution

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will check in more depth as you suggested, but this happening many times, its not at fixed time, due to this my Checkout is stopped working now.